# CSS transform animation issue on safari vs chrome

Tags: css, animation, z-index

I made a replica of my code on codepen to better show the issue.

The animation is working fine on chrome but not on safari.

http://codepen.io/prismosoft/pen/akVzQg

I am applying a scale transform to the wrapper background div while the pusher is rotating and pushed back using translateZ. Now even though the pusher is set to:
`translateZ(-1000px)`

I want the wrapper background to stay behind the pusher as a background. Why is safari not behaving like chrome ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: There a reason why you're using jQuery to do what `:hover` and a well-designed transition timing function can do?

Comment: The code used here is simply to explain the issue and not used in production. Whether using pure css or javascript, the main issue is that the animation behaviour on safari is different than chome and I am wondering why? How can I ensure that the wrapper bg stay behind the pusher during the animation on safari?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue silly me! Since the wrapper bg div is within the wrapper div which has a perspective of 1500px. The issue is resolved by simply moving the wrapper bg outside the wrapper div.